# Data is not pushed to the browser?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP with while (true) where data is sent to browser.

```java
while (true) {
    out.print("pushing some data to browser");
    out.flush();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

It works most the time but rarely the data is not sent to the browser at 1 second interval.

Rather than it is queued up and throws all data at a same time.

Comment: so you are trying to work on some sort of timer?

Comment: Could you show some more relevant code? What is out?

Comment: What are you [_trying to do_](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)?

Comment: `while (true)` never stops, so your document never get rendered.

Comment: maybe it's some sort of live feed; this question isn't clear enough to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @Pescis I have a code which has out.print("<script>funtion()</script>"), the function() is supposed to be called every "x" secs to send some information to the browser(like a pinging mechanism Suku, i think that answers your ques),but at 1 point of time this is not happening but the the information to be sent is stored in some buffer and the next time the buffered data is sent along with the actual information that are sent to the browser. how to overcome this?

Comment: @bmorris591 you may take my comment as an answer

Comment: @RomanC you're right of course, that is the reason why it's not working, but given the OP's comment this **is completely the wrong approach** and fixing it won't really provide a solution to the task the OP is trying to accomplish. This is a classic [XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @bmorris591 This code doesn't compile, throwing Unreachable code exception. +1 for XYProblem.

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
response.setBufferSize(0);
```

in the start of your code block. The response is always buffered by default. You may add this line to disable buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Roman C is right it doesn't compile as posted. But if you fix that you will see that it does work in Firefox and Chrome. 
But, IE is different. It waits until it gets a fair amount of text to begin rendering.

```
IE needs some text here. zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzz I guess this enough for IE to start to render now.
<%
  int x = 0;
  while (x < 10) {
     out.print("pushing some data to browser");
     out.flush();
     try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  }
  x++;
}
%>
```